# Rearrange method parameters in IntelliJ with keyboard shortcut

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ I can easily rearrange the order of statements (or whole methods for that part) by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>).

I was wondering whether there's a shortcut to change the order of method parameters as easily, so that

```
public void sth(String a, String b) {...}
```

will become

```
public void sth(String b, String a) {...}
```

with the stroke of a keyboard shortcut (assuming my cursor is positioned on one of the parameters).

It would be enough for me, if IntelliJ would just reorder the parameters. That is, this need not trigger a whole *Refactor > Change method signature* thing.

Comment: How should this behave when having three or more parameters? :)

Comment: Say my cursor is on the second parameter: Shifting it up, it should become the first. Shifting it down, it should become the last.

Comment: One parameter moved up or down at a time! I'd love to be able to do this featue!

Comment: `Ctrl+F6` and then `Alt+Up` or `Alt+Down` to move a parameter?

Comment: I know, but that's three shortcuts instead of one :) `⌘-F6`, then `Alt-↑/↓` and `Enter` *and* involves the opening of a dialog, which is a bit more intrusive to my workflow.

Comment: Do you really change you signatures so often that showing a dialog might be that intrusive? :) As far as I know, IDEA seems not to have such a feature, so no a special shortcut could be bound to it, unfortunately. I think that the JetBrains team intentionally use a dialog, because this operation might be too expensive/long-to-run for a simple quick reorder shortcut, especially for large projects. Re-ordering lines is much cheaper.

Comment: Yeah, more often than you would think. When I start to flesh out a method I usually `Alt-Enter`  to add additional parameters when needed. When I'm done I then rearrange the parameters to be in a more logical order. Plus, I think it would be really nice to have this shortcut for method calls as well. (Man, how often did I get the order wrong when working with legacy APIs with more than 4 or 5 parameters of the same type! uhg!)

Answer (score 233, accepted):

Since IDEA 16 EAP, there's an action for that. It's in the menu:

**Code | Move Element Left/Right**

Keyboard shortcuts are <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right</kbd> (<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right</kbd> for OSX).

See http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/01/intellij-idea-16-eap-improves-editor-and-vcs-integration/ for more details.

Comment: Good, but Lyubomyr Shaydariv answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35359882/4024146 is much better, because it do refactor and change a dependencies on changes of parameters. This just switch parameters for this methos, but not method calls from another methods.

You don¨t need make macro for it, just CTRL+F6 and use ALT + ↓

Comment: @mtrakal they're two different things.  When I'm composing a method, I don't need the heavyweight (slow) refactoring - I just want to easily move parameters.  The real problem with this one is that I often have parameters on separate lines, so this doesn't work.  (I really want a move-previous and move-next, not a left and right.)

Comment: If you have multiple cursor on several parameters of different methods, they can be moved together.

Comment: NOTE:  This does NOT change the order of any _usage_ of the parameter!  Be very careful.

Comment: Not changing the order of the usage of a parameter is sometimes what you need. Intellij's main change signature refactoring missed some items, and I had to adjust them manually.

Comment: (add-on to @WesternGun comment) vars on multiple lines can be selected with options for [Multiple cursors and selection ranges](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/multicursor.html)

Answer (score 28):

I'm not sure if it's possible in IDEA, but you might try to use editor macros for two-parameter methods:

- *Editor -> Macros -> Start Macro Recording*
- Record your macro:

  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to open the *Change Signature* dialog
  - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> to swap the first and the second parameter
  - <kbd>Tab</kbd> to deactivate the *Parameters* tab and let the *Refactor* button get the focus
  - <kbd>Enter</kbd> to close the dialog at perform refactoring
- *Editor -> Macros -> Stop Macro Recording* and give a name to your macro, let's say "Swap method parameters 1 and 2".

And then access your macro via the *Editor -> Macros* menu or assign a custom shortcut to it in *Settings -> Keymap -> Main menu/Edit/Macros/Swap method parameters 1 and 2*. It looks a very dirty and context-free way to me, but maybe it could help you a little.

Comment: This fix the issue for me to refactor around 500~ methods.

Answer (score 21):

On Ubuntu 18.04 the default shortcut is Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Super+Left/Right to move an argument left or right in position.

This is as it is setup to not clash with some of the new OS level shortcuts

Comment: thanks, even though it requires finger gymnastics, this is so much better than needing to bind a separate key.

Comment: Thanks. It's shown as C+A+S+left in Code menu, but grayed out. I was wondering why until seeing this.